# Proving $f$ is differentiable everywhere where $f$ is a vector times a matrix.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $A$ be an $n\times m$ matrix and let $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ be a vector valued function defined by $f(x)=Ax$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at every point and $f'(x)=A$.

Does the fact that $f$ is differentiable have anything to do with both $x$ and $A$ being differentiable?

Also, how do we solve for the derivative?

Comment: Use the definition.  (No, really.)

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x+y)=A(x+y)=Ax+Ay=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(tx)=tAx = tf(x)$, the function $f$ is linear. As such, $f'(x)=A$ at any $x$. This is an immediate consequence of the definition of derivative: just try!